# SP-API : can I have a dynamic response for the listingsapi on the sandbox network?

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I am testing the Selling partner API of amazon.
and I am using a generated Java SDK.

for the putListingsItem and getListingsItem methods the response is always the same.

Is it a static operation?

is there a way to have a dynamic response for these operations?